# Filtering a dataframe and updating a column with value from another

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset containing origin and destination columns (sample below). I need to select all rows with the value of "W" (Works from Home) in Dest2 and the update this with the value of Origin. So the value for row 4 in Dest2 would then become BB.

I have tried a number of options using filtering and subsets and can update the required row but all other rows then get a value of NA.

Is there a way of only updating the rows where Dest2 = W?

```
> TestData #loads it in
      JobID Origin Dest Dest2
  1      1     AA   BB    BB
  2      2     AA   BB    BB
  3      3     BB   AA    AA
  4      4     BB    W     W
  5      5     CC   BB    BB
  6      6     CC   BB    BB
  7      7     CC   BB    BB
  8      8     CC   CC    CC
  9      9     CC   CC    CC
 10    10     DD   AA    AA
```

Comment: `TestData$Dest2[TestData$Dest2 == 'W'] <- TestData$Origin[TestData$Dest2 == 'W']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestData$Dest2 <- ifelse(TestData$Dest2 == "W", TestData$Origin, TestData$Dest2)`

Comment: You need `..., TestData$Dest2 == TestData$Origin, ...`

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Sotos. This code is problematic. It should be `TestData$Dest2 <- ifelse(TestData$Dest2 == "W", TestData$Origin, TestData$Dest2)`

Comment: Thank you gentlemen! I've corrected.

Comment: Thank you.That's worked perfectly.  I'm sure a very basic question but just getting started on R. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know a solution using `data.table`:

```
 setDT(TestData)
 TestData[Dest2 == "W", Dest2 := Origin]
 TestData
#JobID Origin Dest Dest2
#1:     1     AA   BB    BB
#2:     2     AA   BB    BB
#3:     3     BB   AA    AA
#4:     4     BB    W    BB
#5:     5     CC   BB    BB
#6:     6     CC   BB    BB
#7:     7     CC   BB    BB
#8:     8     CC   CC    CC
#9:     9     CC   CC    CC
#10:    10     DD   AA    AA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
TestData2 <- TestData %>%
  mutate(Dest2 = ifelse(Dest2 %in% "W", Origin, Dest2))
```

Notice the use of `%in%`. If you want to match multiple strings, not just `W`, `%in%` could be a better choice.

#### Data Preparation

```
TestData <- read.table(text = "JobID Origin Dest Dest2
1     AA   BB    BB
2     AA   BB    BB
3     BB   AA    AA
4     BB    W     W
5     CC   BB    BB
6     CC   BB    BB
7     CC   BB    BB
8     CC   CC    CC
9     CC   CC    CC
10     DD   AA    AA",
                       header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```